# Installing QGIS in Ubuntu 14

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, qgis

I've upgraded my Ubuntu 12.04 to 14, and now I can't run QGIS.
I've tried to re-install, installed QGIS 2.4, QGIS 2.0 with no luck.

After adding Trusty repositories (to install QGIS 2.4) or regular ubuntu repositories (for 2.0), I get this error message.

It seems I've problems with packages:
qgis-providers
 qgis
 qgis-plugin-globe
 qgis-plugin-grass
I don't know what can I do now.
¿Maybe downgrade to Ubuntu 12 again?

The message:

```
> 
Setting up qgis-providers (2.0.1-2build2) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: error while loading shared libraries: libnetcdf.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up qgis-common (2.0.1-2build2) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 2.0.1-2build2); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.
>
dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up qgis-plugin-globe-common (2.0.1-2build2) ...
Setting up libosgearth2 (2.4.0+dfsg-6) ...
Setting up libosgearthsymbology2 (2.4.0+dfsg-6) ...
Setting up libosgearthfeatures2 (2.4.0+dfsg-6) ...
Setting up libosgearthannotation2 (2.4.0+dfsg-6) ...
Setting up libosgearthutil2 (2.4.0+dfsg-6) ...
Setting up libosgearthqt2 (2.4.0+dfsg-6) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-globe:
 qgis-plugin-globe depends on qgis (= 2.0.1-2build2); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.
>
dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-globe (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up qgis-plugin-grass-common (2.0.1-2build2) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 2.0.1-2build2); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.
>
dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 qgis-plugin-globe
 qgis-plugin-grass
Error in function: 
Setting up qgis-providers (2.0.1-2build2) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: error while loading shared libraries: libnetcdf.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 2.0.1-2build2); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.
>
dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 2.0.1-2build2); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.
>
dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-globe:
 qgis-plugin-globe depends on qgis (= 2.0.1-2build2); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.
>
dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-globe (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not get to install either but did get a work around.

The ubuntugis project provides newer versions of various FOSSGIS packages, QGIS being one of them.

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```